# Do the terms lock convoying, lock contention and hot locks refer to the same issue?

Tags: multithreading, performance, visual-studio, locking, multicore

For my bachelor thesis I have to evaluate common problems on multicore-systems for performance issues.
Reading some books whoch discuss about poorly behaving multithtreaded programs due to the incorrect use of locks, I have come across to the terminologies

**Lock convoying** (some IEEE papers, books)

**Heavy lock contention** (in the Intel book written by Shameem Akther,...)

and

**Hot Locks** (only in Darryl Glove's Multicore Application programming book)

For me reading the theory they all refer to the same thing, but today respectively now for evaluating my problem-showing-programs I have come across to the Visual Studio extension Concurrency Visualizer. For some tutorial purposes I found this msdn page:
[Common Patterns for Poorly-Behaved Multithreaded Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee329530.aspx)

There you can see that lock convoying and lock contention have their own part of example pattern image. But both refer to serial execution due to locks.

So are these the same problem but given different names? If not, what is the difference between them

Comment: Has nobody a clue for the question?

Comment: Lock contention and "hot" locks are general terms, whereas lock convoying is a particular degradation scenario.